# Is “Write something also on. . . .” ok?

Tags: grammaticality, adverb-position

In the following sentence, is the usage of *also* considered grammatically correct, or is there something wrong with it?

> Write something also on an alternative approach to this problem;
>   explain the pros and cons of that alternative.

The sentence doesn't feel right, but I thought I would seek the input of the well-informed before jumping to conclusions.

I would like to make it known that I am not the one responsible for this sentence, nor will the person responsible ever know of this inquiry — it is purely for the sake of self-satisfaction.

Comment: Very close related, and almost certainly somewhere a dupe: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/54327
http://english.stackexchange.com/q/399
http://english.stackexchange.com/q/8371
http://english.stackexchange.com/q/68568
http://english.stackexchange.com/q/106165
http://english.stackexchange.com/q/165431
http://english.stackexchange.com/q/111742
http://english.stackexchange.com/q/30366
http://english.stackexchange.com/q/38730
http://english.stackexchange.com/q/30366
and many many many many many many many many many many many many many many many many many many many many many many many many more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s not flat-out “wrong”, but this doesn’t sound anything as good:

- Write something **also** on an alternative approach to this problem.

As any of these:

1. **Also** write something on an alternative approach to this problem.
2. Write something on an alternative approach to this problem **as well**.
3. Write something on an alternative approach to this problem, **too**.

The first is probably the best of those.

Comment: FWIW, I disagree. All of your 1,2,3 *and* the OP sound fine to me. I would use them in different contexts, no doubt, but each sounds OK.  (However, I'd suggest splitting the OP sentence in two at the semicolon.)